# How to set the rules depending on the entity field?

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, business-rules

## Situation

using Cake 3.2.6

in my CostItemsTable,

I have a `buildRules` function

```
/**
 * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
 * application integrity.
 *
 * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
 * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
 */
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{

    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['foreign_model_id'], 'ForeignModels'));
    return $rules;
}
```

## What I want

My CostItems Entity has 2 fields called `foreign_model` and `foreign_model_id`.

`foreign_model_id` acts as the foreign key. `foreign_model` acts as the Table that will be Parent to the CostItems table.

so a typical record can have `foreign_model` as GeneralCostCategories and `foreign_model_id` as 1.

## What I tried

I tried to log the $this inside the buildRules function but I find nothing useful that allows me to dynamically change this rule.

```
   $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['foreign_model_id'], 'ForeignModels'));
```

to

```
   $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['foreign_model_id'], $entity->foreign_model));
```

Comment: Note that, by default, when you load a CostItem, the `foreign_model` may be overwritten by the entity referenced by `foreign_model_id`; changing the column name to `foreign_model_name` or some such would eliminate this naming issue. (I think there may also be a configuration you can use to change the property name that will be used for the entity, but I haven't looked into that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to solve this, here's two of them.

** It should be noted that the following is all untested example code!*

### Custom rules

You could implement a custom rule, either as a callback, or as a rule class, where the entity is going to be passed to, and then run the exists check accordingly with the data from the entity.

**callback**

```
use Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface;
use Cake\ORM\Rule\ExistsIn;

// ...

$rules->add(
    function (EntityInterface $entity, array $options) {
        $check = new ExistsIn(['foreign_model_id'], $entity->get('foreign_model'));
        return $check($entity, $options);
    },
    '_existsIn',
    [
        'errorField' => 'foreign_model_id',
        'message' => __d('cake', 'This value does not exist')
    ]
);
```

**custom rule class, src/Model/Rule/MyExitsIn.php**

```
namespace App\Model\Rule;

use Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface;
use Cake\ORM\Rule\ExistsIn;

class MyExistsIn extends ExistsIn
{
    public function __construct($fields)
    {
        parent::__construct($fields, null);
    }

    public function __invoke(EntityInterface $entity, array $options)
    {
        $this->_repository = $entity->get('foreign_model');
        return parent::__invoke($entity, $options);
    }
}
```

```
use App\Model\Rule\MyExistsIn;

// ...

$rules->add(
    new MyExistsIn(['foreign_model_id']),
    '_existsIn',
    [
        'errorField' => 'foreign_model_id',
        'message' => __d('cake', 'This value does not exist')
    ]
);
```

### Build rules on the fly

Or use the `Model.beforeRules` event, which receives the entity too, and modify the rules checker object on the fly.

**in your table class**

```
use Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface;
use Cake\Event\Event;

// ...

public function beforeRules(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, \ArrayObject $options, $operation)
{
    /* @var $rulesChecker \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker */
    $rulesChecker = $this->rulesChecker();
    $rulesChecker->add(
        $rulesChecker->existsIn(['foreign_model_id'], $entity->get('foreign_model'))
    );
}
```

### See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Validation > Creating a Rules Checker](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#creating-a-rules-checker)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Validation > Creating Custom Rule objects](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#creating-custom-rule-objects)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Table Objects > Lifecycle Callbacks > beforeRules](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforerules)**